# Restoring /etc/mail to defaults

Tags: mail, sendmail

I ran into issues configuring Sendmail and messed up the `/etc/mail` folder's files, so I deleted `/etc/mail` entirely. How can I now start fresh in my journey of attempting to configure Sendmail by restoring the `/etc/mail` folder with its default files?

Comment: You could try running `dpkg -S /etc/mail` and then re-installing the packages it identifies

Comment: I just did exactly the same thing, and nothing seems to help.  Did you ever figure out how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Having experimented further, I used apt to remove all the sendmail packages and then did

```
apt install sendmail-cf sendmail-base sendmail-bin sendmail-doc
```

and I now have most (or all) of what I remember from /etc/mail.  Of course, I still don't know how to get it doing what I want, but at least I can try things now.